# Assigning a given value if a function returns an error

Tags: function-construction, warning-messages

This question has to do with error handling, I guess.

I am using Brent's Method in order to numerically find the root of a function. This is just an example of what I am doing:

```
functionexample[a_, b_, c_, x_] := Sin[a*x] + Cos[b*x] + Log[c*x]
rootexample[a_, b_, c_, result_] := 
 FindRoot[functionexample[a, b, c, x] == result, {x, 1, 12}, 
    Method -> "Brent", PrecisionGoal -> 16][[1]][[2]]
a = 1
b = 1
c = 1
Plot[{functionexample[a, b, c, x], 2, 4}, {x, 1, 12}, 
 PlotRange -> Automatic]
rootexample[a, b, c, 2]
rootexample[a, b, c, 4]
```

And this is what I get:

[image: MWE Mathematica]

So, at the end `rootexample[1, 1, 1, 4]` (that's when Brent's Method returns an error message) seems to take value 4.

I would like to define `rootexample[a_, b_, c_, result_]` in such a way that when an error arises in the root finding procedure, an special value is assigned to the result of the function (something like `""` or `Null` or `None` or something similar).

[**EDIT:** The idea is: if there is a root, then return the root; if not, then return `None`.]

I mean, I would like to properly control/handle possible errors coming from Brent's Method within the definition of the function `rootexample`.

I have no idea about how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like stated in the duplicate's link:

```
functionexample[a_, b_, c_, x_] := Sin[a*x] + Cos[b*x] + Log[c*x]
rootexample[a_, b_, c_, result_] := 
  FindRoot[functionexample[a, b, c, x] == result, {x, 1, 12}, 
    Method -> "Brent", PrecisionGoal -> 16][[1, 2]]
a = 1; b = 1; c = 1;
Quiet[Table[
  Check[rootexample[a, b, c, i], "NaN", {FindRoot::bbrac}], {i, -5, 5}],
  {FindRoot::bbrac}]
```

> {NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,5.68433,NaN,NaN,NaN}

Or if you want it as a function:

```
quietrootexample[a_, b_, c_, result_] := 
  Quiet@Check[rootexample[a, b, c, result], "NaN", {FindRoot::bbrac}]
quietrootexample[a, b, c, #] & /@ Range@5
```

> {NaN,5.68433,NaN,NaN,NaN}

Comment: Thank you. I don't know what to do about the "duplicating" issue. I think the other question is very similar, but I wanted it to be applied to a function. In fact, even if I had seen that possible duplicate, I would still have asked my question. And, actually... I still have to check and understand what is the meaning of that syntax, with `@` and so on —I am still a beginner on Mathematica.

Comment: @Vicent `Quiet[...]` is equivalent to `Quiet@...`

Comment: Thank you! I find the syntax of Mathematica a little bit strange sometimes, but it is very powerful, I think.